# Python smtplib and configparser as function

Tags: python, function, variables, smtplib, configparser

Hello I try to make a small monitoring, and in the monitoring.py, it should send a email with function sendmail.sende(). But i think, i got issues with variables. Could you give me some tips, what i do wrong please?
This is the sendmail.py

```
def sende():
    import smtplib
    import configparser
    from email.message import Message

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    absender=(config['SMTP']['absender'])
    password=(config['SMTP']['password'])
    empfaenger=(config['SMTP']['empfaenger'])
    smtphost=(config['SMTP']['smtphost'])
    port=int(config['SMTP']['port'])

    def readLastLog():
        log=open('log', 'r')
        for line in log:
            last= line
        print (last)
        log.close()

    #check for if variables is correct
    print("Email Config:")
    print(absender, '\n',empfaenger,'\n',smtphost,'\n',port)

    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=smtphost, port=port)

    #do I need realy need this?
    #server.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'LOGIN PLAIN'

    nachricht = Message()
    nachricht.set_payload(readLastLog())
    nachricht["Subject"] = "Kritische Warnung - Hardlimit erreicht"
    nachricht["FROM"] = absender
    nachricht["To"] = empfaenger

    server.login(absender, password)
    server.sendmail(absender, empfaenger, nachricht.as_string())
    server.quit()

sende()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sendmail.py", line 42, in <module>
    sende()
  File "./sendmail.py", line 38, in sende
    server.login(absender, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 729, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 720, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')
```

Comment: The error comes from the authentication part. Did you control that the username and password are correct, and can you send messages from *something else* through that server? If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not describe what is going wrong, so just guessing. But the function `readLastLog` is wrong:

- it only print to stdout and does not return anything - so actually returns `None`
- it is later used to initialize the payload which gives only `nachricht.set_payload(None)`

Some other immediate improvements:

- declaring a function inside another one is not wrong and have real use cases, but here I really wonder why `readLastLog` is defined inside `sende` body...
- as you have built a Message with its `To:` and `From:` header, you could use the `send_message` function:

  ```
  ...
  server.send_message(nachricht)
  server.quit()
  ```

Comment: Oh gosh, yea i forgot it - sorry about that 
updated the post - error at the end

Answer (score 0):

So i changed the readLastLog with a return, and made a seperate function,
Anyway that hasnt fixed the skript, so problem here was maybe with my @web.de mail.
Changed to a own mailserver with other email. Now i do reciving emails.
Sorry for taking ur time.

```
def readLastLog():
    log=open('log', 'r')
    for line in log:
        lastlog= line
    print (lastlog)
    log.close()
    return lastlog

def sende():
    import smtplib
    import configparser
    from email.message import Message

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    absender=(config['SMTP']['absender'])
    password=(config['SMTP']['password'])
    empfaenger=(config['SMTP']['empfaenger'])
    smtphost=(config['SMTP']['smtphost'])
    port=int(config['SMTP']['port'])


    #check for if variables is correct
    print("Email Config:")
    print(absender, '\n',empfaenger,'\n',smtphost,'\n',port)

    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=smtphost, port=port)

    #do I need realy need this?
    #server.esmtp_features['auth'] = 'LOGIN PLAIN'

    nachricht = Message()
    nachricht.set_payload(readLastLog())
    nachricht["Subject"] = "Kritische Warnung - Hardlimit erreicht"
    nachricht["FROM"] = absender
    nachricht["To"] = empfaenger

    server.login(absender, password)
    server.sendmail(absender, empfaenger, nachricht.as_string())
    server.quit()
```